# dateRangeInput, selectInput and reactives functions R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive, shiny-reactivity

I really need your help.
I am new in R shiny and I have to use 2 reactives functions.
I have a table of a DataBase which columns `(id_cli, val_cli, date_cli)`
example (1, 12, 2020-02-01); (1,30,2020-02-02); (2, 80,2020-02-03) etc.
I want to select the id_cli using the function `selectInput` and from there select a date range using the `dateRangeInput` function

This is my code :

```
date1 <- seq(from = min(clo$date_cli), to = max(clo$date_cli), by= "days")

tweet <- data.frame(date = date1, clo$val_cli, clo$id_cli)

selectInput(inputId="cli", label= "Choose client", choices = tweet$id_cli)

dateRangeInput(inputId ="date", label ="Choose date", start = min(tweet$date_cli)
               end = max(tweet$date_cli),
               min = min(tweet$date_cli),
               max = max(tweet$date_cli)
)


query1 <-reactive({
tweet %>%
select(id_cli, val_cli, date_cli) %>%
filer(id_cli ==input$cli)
})

query2 <-reactive ({
query1()
filter(tweet, between(date, input$date[1] input$date[2])
})
```

The code takes all the date range of data but does not select by `id_cli` which is `input$cli`
Someone can help me please ?

Comment: `renderPlot({ggplot(query2(), aes(x=date, y =val_cli)) + geom_line(size=1) +xlab("date"), ylab("value")  }) `

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It will be easier to help you if you provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You also may have a misspelling: `filer(id_cli ==input$cli)` should be `filter(id_cli ==input$cli)`?

Comment: You really need to provide a reproducible example we can run.

Comment: Yes it is `filter(id_cli ==input$cli) ` .

Answer (score 0):

`query2` is reacting after `query1` changes, but it's not using `query1`. It's still using `tweet`. Try:

```
query2 <-reactive ({
    query1() %>% between(date, input$date[1] input$date[2])
})
```